# Python: Taking a rectangular subset of Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

How come if

```
c = np.arange(100).reshape([10,10])
```

then

```
c[0:6,2:4]
```

can successfully take a rectangular subset of the data, but this can't?

```
c[np.arange(6),np.arange(2,4)]
```

I have the following code, but I can't get the subset of data I need for it to work, please can you help me fix this? Thanks

```
# Box length in z-direction
z_length = features['Radial_pktrD'].values * 2
# Box width in x-direction
x_width = features['Radial_Width_50'].values

# Create array of index numbers for z and x arrays
zindex = np.arange(0,len(z),1)
xindex = np.arange(0,len(x),1)

# Box1 - bottom left (peak)
zind = zindex[(z < radial_centre_z) & (z > radial_centre_z-z_length)]
xind = xindex[(x < radial_centre_x) & (x > radial_centre_x - x_width)]
x_peak1,z_peak1 = np.where(radial[xind,zind]==np.max(radial[xind,zind]))
```

---

I have spent a long time searching for the answer to this question and so far I have not found anything that corresponds to using Numpy arrays for index' and how to do it, therefore I don't believe this question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36733557/numpy-advanced-selection-not-working). I am not asking about advanced selection but rather simple selection using Numpy arrays.

---

The error I get is in the line

```
x_peak1,z_peak1 = np.where(radial[xind,zind]==np.max(radial[xind,zind]))
```

The error message is

```
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (19,) (31,)
```

Which I think essentially means you cannot use Numpy arrays in this way

Comment: Because `c[0:6,2:4]` is correct format for slicing and `c[np.arange(6),np.arange(2,4)]` is not, BTW which part of code is not working and what is the error ?

Comment: Couldn't you find a duplicate that doesn't involve selection from a 4d array?  Something that directly compares basic indexing (with slices) and advanced (with lists/arrays)?

Comment: @hpaulj: I could find a duplicate with a 3D array, but nothing 2D.